# Will "soft nucleophiles" undergo 1,4-conjugate addition even if the β-carbon is sterically hindered?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilicity, steric-effects

In general soft nucleophiles do 1,4 conjugate addition to a carbonyl carbon under thermodynamic control. Will soft nucleophiles like organocuprates still preferentially undergo 1,4 addition if the β-carbon is more sterically hindered than the carbonyl carbon?

For example, if I consider the following case

[image: 2-cyclohexylideneacetaldehyde]

should I just accept it as a rule of thumb that these "soft nucleophiles" undergo 1,4-nucleophilic addition to the carbonyl group, or does it vary depending on the structure and the situation?

In addition to the example above, what happens if there is a methyl group at C-2 of the ring?

[image: 2-(2-methylcyclohexylidene)acetaldehyde]

Comment: I don't see much steric hindrance in the example case.

Comment: Regarding your edit: The terms 'ortho', 'meta', and 'para' are only applicable to benzene rings. You have a cyclohexane ring here, those terms are not correct.

Comment: @orthocresol Though I recall "ortho product" and "para product / selectivity"  when describing the outcome of asymetric dienes (e.g., methacrylate) with asymetric dienes (e.g., 2-methyl-buta-1,3-diene) in the course of Diels-Alder reactions, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood Hmm, I recall Clayden uses these terms, but I think it's meant to be just a helpful mnemonic, not a serious scientific terminology.

Answer (score 4):

Your line of thought possibly is influenced by the [Walden inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walden_inversion) which is characteristic for the nucleophilic *substitution* mechanism of $\mathrm{S_N2}$ where steric hindrance affects the rate when this umbrella-like structure flips upon entry of the nuclophile and departure of the nucleofuge around a formally $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized center:

[image]

([credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walden_inversion))

The reaction shown by you however is *an addition* on to a carbon with molecular orbitals formally hybridized as $\mathrm{sp^2}$.  Similar to the [Bürgi–Dunitz trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrgi%E2%80%93Dunitz_angle) for the entry of a nucleophile on to a $\ce{C=O}$ bond **a)** it is plausible that the angle of attack for the 1,4-addition **b)** equally is tilted, rather than an attack from the back.

[image]

(composed with a picture from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrgi%E2%80%93Dunitz_angle))

Comment: My impression (I never did much real-life organic chemistry) is that depending on the size of R and R', nucleophilic attack on the alkene (even via the B–D trajectory) can be quite tough: it probably depends on how big the nucleophile is, too. However, I can't say that I'm an expert on this, so had better leave it to the proper organic chemists :-)